# How to use a .NET 4.0 application on .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm the end-user of a program that relies on WPF from .NET 4.0.  Installing .NET 4.5 causes the CAD to break, but I'd really like to use Visual Studio 2012.

Is there any way to maintain compatibility with the .NET 4.0-reliant application while having .NET 4.5?

Comment: .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 won't exist side-by-side by default (http://reddevnews.com/blogs/rdn-express/2011/11/back-to-app-migrations-with-ms-net-vnext.aspx).  I'm hoping that there might be some reasonable trick to force separate installations.

Comment: Also should note that I did check with the vendor, but they're not in any hurry to fix this issue.

Comment: Dump the vendor or complain more frequently.  We can't help you with that.

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer I am from .NET Framework Compatibility Team. I'd like to help take a look at what's going on. I need access to the program that you are using to investigate. Could you send me program that you are using on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com?

Comment: It's now half a year later.  The vendor eventually released a newer version that works with .NET 4.5, resolving the issue.  I was unable to find any other solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Sadly the relevant software package was unique, so dumping the vendor wasn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed .NET 4.5 updates your existing .NET 4.0 installation, and so you won't be able to install them separately. The .NET guys intend for .NET 4.5 not to break any .NET 4 apps, and implement fixes for the cases where there are problems (even now, after .NET 4.5 has been released).

Check that you've installed the recent update to improve compatibility (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645). If that doesn't fix your app, report the problem to *netfx45compat@microsoft.com*.

In summary - there's not much you can do unless the vendor or Microsoft helps. There are ways in .NET 4.5 to improve backward-compatibility with .NET 4, and Microsoft seems keen to address these issues in ongoing updates, so make sure you report your case to them.

There are some more details on the .NET 4.5 roll-out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/17/net-framework-4-5-off-to-a-great-start.aspx).

Comment: You were correct.  There wasn't anything that could've been done until the vendor helped by releasing a new version several months later.

Answer (score -1):

You need both .Net 4.0 *and* 4.5 installed.

Edit: Apparently not. For previous versions this is true (3.5 and 4 for example) but for 4 and 4.5 it'd seem not.

However 4.5 does have some changes in that may affect 4.0 applications causing them to break. You should contact the application vendor for an update. Failing that you could try running it in XP compatibility mode.

Comment: .NET 4.5 replaces .NET 4.0, right?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx

Comment: Sadly, the vendor has no plans to fix this.  I'm hoping that there may be some trick short of a virtual machine to get it working.

Comment: You could try running it in XP compatibility mode, since .Net 4.5 doesn't support XP it may end up using the older libraries.

Comment: Since MSDN claims that the .NET 4.0 assemblies are replaced upon installing .NET 4.5, I think that I'd need to find some way to reinstall .NET 4.0 .. elsewhere?  Then force the program in question to somehow go to that installation instead of the 4.5 installation?  Maybe there's not a reasonable solution here.